# How can I fill down values in postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, window-functions

I have a dataset that comprises one row per event per issue. I have a date table that I'm using as a date scaffold. I'm wanting to fill down the issue status, so that I have the issue status represented each month that the issue is open even if there is not an event for the issue. Multiple events can occur for an issue each day such as assigned, commented, opened, closed, reopened.

**Actual result:** My code currently continues to fill down the status even after the issue is closed.

**Expected result:** Only fill down the status from the month the issue is opened until it is closed, noting that the same issue can be opened again and subsequently closed. In the sample below, there should be no derived issue status for the month of December, because the issue was closed in November.

```
WITH cte (cal_month) as 
(
    SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-07-01T00:00:00')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-08-01T00:00:00')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-09-01T00:00:00')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-10-01T00:00:00')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-11-01T00:00:00')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-12-01T00:00:00')
),
cte_2 (cal_month, issue_id, version, action_day, action_month, issue_status)
as 
(
SELECT m.cal_month
        , issue_id
        , version    
        , date_trunc('day', action_timestamp) as action_day 
        , date_trunc('month', action_timestamp) as action_month
        , issue_status 
        , SUM(CASE WHEN issue_status IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY cal_month, issue_status, version) as grp
FROM cte m
LEFT JOIN issue_history h
    ON m.cal_month = date_trunc('month', action_timestamp)
    AND issue_id IN (23865)
ORDER BY cal_month, issue_id, version
)
SELECT *
        , first_value(issue_status) over (partition by grp) as derived_issue_status
FROM cte_2
ORDER BY cal_month, issue_id, version
```

Sample output from the code

| cal_month | issue_id | version | action_day | action_month | issue_status | grp | derived_issue_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 1 | 2021-07-25T00:00:00 | 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 1 | For Resolution |
| 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 2 | 2021-07-25T00:00:00 | 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 2 | For Resolution |
| 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 3 | 2021-07-26T00:00:00 | 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 3 | For Resolution |
| 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 4 | 2021-07-26T00:00:00 | 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 4 | For Resolution |
| 2021-08-01T00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | For Resolution |
| 2021-09-01T00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | For Resolution |
| 2021-10-01T00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | For Resolution |
| 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 5 | 2021-11-09T00:00:00 | 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 5 | For Resolution |
| 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 6 | 2021-11-09T00:00:00 | 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 6 | For Resolution |
| 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 7 | 2021-11-09T00:00:00 | 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | For Resolution | 7 | For Resolution |
| 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | 23865 | 8 | 2021-11-15T00:00:00 | 2021-11-01T00:00:00 | Closed | 8 | Closed |
| 2021-12-01T00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 8 | Closed |

Comment: As a side note: your `cal_month` can be simplified to `SELECT * from generate_series(date '2021-07-01', date '2021-12-01',  interval ' 1 month') `

Comment: if you add to `cte_2` a WHERE-clause with `status != 'Closed' the record for december should not exist.   BTW:  On `2021-08-01` is do seen an issue_id of `null` is that really what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WITH cte_2 AS 
(
SELECT m.cal_month
     , issue_id
     , version    
     , date_trunc('day', action_timestamp) as action_day 
     , date_trunc('month', action_timestamp) as action_month
     , issue_status 
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE issue_status IS NOT NULL) OVER (ORDER BY cal_month, issue_status, version) as grp
     , (jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(issue_status)) FILTER (WHERE issue_status IS NOT NULL) OVER (ORDER BY cal_month, issue_status, version))->'-1' as derived_issue_status
  FROM generate_series(date '2021-07-01', date '2021-12-01',  interval ' 1 month') m
  LEFT JOIN issue_history h
    ON m.cal_month = date_trunc('month', action_timestamp)
   AND issue_id IN (23865)
 ORDER BY cal_month, issue_id, version
)
SELECT m.cal_month
     , issue_id
     , version
     , action_day 
     , action_month
     , issue_status 
     , grp
     , CASE
         WHEN derived_issue_status = 'Closed' AND issue_status IS NULL
         THEN NULL
         ELSE derived_issue_status
       END AS derived_issue_status
FROM cte_2
ORDER BY cal_month, issue_id, version
```

**Propositions of changes :**

(1) As proposed by @a_horse_with_no_name, cte is suppressed and replaced by `generate_series(date '2021-07-01', date '2021-12-01',  interval ' 1 month')` in cte2

(2) In cte2 :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN issue_status IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY cal_month, issue_status, version) as grp
```

replaced by

```
count(*) FILTER (WHERE issue_status IS NOT NULL) OVER (ORDER BY cal_month, issue_status, version) as grp
```

even if `grp` in not used anymore in the final query because `derived_issue_status` is calculated in cte2 with the new statement :

```
(jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(issue_status)) FILTER (WHERE issue_status IS NOT NULL) OVER (ORDER BY cal_month, issue_status, version))->>'-1' as derived_issue_status
```

(3) A `CASE` is added in the final query in order to display derived_issue_status = NULL when the current issue_status is NULL and the last non-NULL issue_status = 'Closed'

Comment: Thanks for that! This is almost there. I only want to have calendar months for each month that the issue is open even if there is not an event for the issue. I need to generate a date series for the next 12 months, so there will be a lot of empty rows generated long after an issue is closed. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I've approached it like this. 

cte 1 create a partition for each set of open and close events per issue using COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE issue_status = 1) OVER (PARTITION BY issue_id ORDER BY version) as grp. In the example above, all of these events would be in grp 1. If the issue was reopened there would be grps 1 and 2. 
cte 2 retrieves the earliest open and latest close within the grp. These values are passed into generate_series for each issue 
join cte2 to the cte suggested by you and drop the case statement that checks for the null and closed status

Thoughts?