# `ffill` equivalent in SQL

Tags: postgresql

Assume I have the following table:

```
day0, measurement0
day1, null
day2, measurement1
day3, null
day4, null
```

I want to get something like this:

```
day0, measurement0
day1, measurement0
day2, measurement1
day3, measurement1
day4, measurement1
```

I've seen other solution to this problem, e.g. [How can I fill down values in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315404/how-can-i-fill-down-values-in-postgres) but I don't get it. Even if I understood it, those solutions are too complex for everyday use, and after few months nobody will understand such code.

Is there anything simple like Pandas `df.ffill()` for SQL (especially for PostgreSQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 : using a window function**

You can use a `window function` while ordering the days by descendent order, selecting the range from the current row and all the next rows (in the descendent order), filtering on the non null values only, and selecting the first non null value that is found :

```
SELECT day, (array_agg(measurement) FILTER (WHERE measurement IS NOT NULL) OVER (ORDER BY day DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1]
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY day
```

The window function `first_value(measurement)` would be perfect but it can't be used with a `FILTER` clause, so it is replaced by the aggregate function `array_agg(measurement)` whose first element is the only one selected.

**Solution 2 : using a specific aggregate function**

This solution comes from https://patternmatchers.wordpress.com/2021/06/11/ignore-nulls-in-postgres/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coalesce_sfunc(x anyelement, y anyelement)
    returns anyelement immutable parallel safe language sql AS
$$
select coalesce(x, y);
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE find_last_ignore_nulls(anyelement) (
    sfunc = coalesce_r_sfunc,
    stype = anyelement
);

SELECT day, find_last_ignore_nulls(measurement)
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY day
```

Both solutions have the same query plan, so no big difference in terms of performance.

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nsi2-F-e)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the meantime I also found another 'short' answer - https://patternmatchers.wordpress.com/2021/06/11/ignore-nulls-in-postgres/
It's both shorter than your answer (no `filter` clause) and also longer (requires custom aggregate function `find_last_ignore_nulls`).

Comment: @iirekm : using a custom aggregate function is a smart solution. I update my answer to include it, but after test in dbfiddle, both solutions have similar query plans so no big performance gap between both solutions. By the way, I will change a bit the function you found on the web to make it working in your case.